# What is the most efficient way to perform a large and slow batch job on GAE

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, cron, batch-processing, google-cloud-datastore

Say I have a retrieved a list of objects from NDB. I have a method that I can call to update the state of these objects, which I have to do every 15 minutes. These updates take ~30 seconds due to API calls that it has to make.

How would I go ahead and process a list of >1,000 objects?

Example of an approach that would be very slow:

```
my_objects = [...] # list of objects to process
for object in my_objects:
  object.process_me() # takes around 30 seconds
  object.put()
```

Comment: use a task with async (ndb tasklets) query map: docs https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

- you can run a task with a query cursor, that processes only N entities each time. When these are processed, and there are more entities to go, you fire another task with the next query cursor.
  Resources: [query cursor](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries?hl=en#Python_Query_cursors), [tasks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/)
- you can run a mapreduce job that will go over all entities in your query in a parallel manner (might require more resources).
  Simple tutorial: [MapReduce on App Engine made easy](http://wisestamp.com/blog/mapreduce-on-app-engine-made-easy/)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using mapreduce for your purposes. When I wanted to update all my > 15000 entities I used [mapreduce](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/).

```
def process(entity):
    # update...
    yield op.db.Put(entity)
```